# Is it possible to uniformly generate a random infinite bitstring lazily?

Tags: haskell, random, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation, state-monad

I tried to build an RNG that uniformly randomly chooses amongst 3 items. Because, the common idiom (something like C's `rand() % 3`) is prone to modulo bias, and thus not uniform.

As per the notion of admissibility, my idea was to uniformly generate a random infinite bitstring, and map it through a function. The following statements shall satisfy:

- The function halts for almost all inputs (This "almost all" is a well-defined notion in measure theory)
- The induced probability distribution over the 3 items is uniform

As such, my sketch of code was, in Haskell:

```
import Data.Word

import System.Random

infixr 5 :!

data InfWord64 = Word64 :! InfWord64

execute :: (InfWord64 -> a) -> IO a
execute f = do
    let getWordString = do
        headWord <- randomIO
        tailWords <- getWordString
        pure (headWord :! tailWords)
    fmap f getWordString

randomOrderingMap :: InfWord64 -> Ordering
randomOrderingMap (headWord :! tailWords)
  | headWord < 0x5555555555555555 = LT
  | 0x5555555555555555 < headWord && headWord < 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = EQ
  | 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA < headWord = GT
  | otherwise = randomOrderingMap tailWords

randomOrdering :: IO Ordering
randomOrdering = execute randomOrderingMap
```

But it doesn't work properly. It seems `execute` would fall into an infinite loop for every input. It seems the monadic statement `headWord <- randomIO` would be executed infinitely.

I would need some kind of lazy `IO`, but it doesn't exist for good reasons. Lazy `ST RealWorld` would be an alternative, but I don't see any way to use this when the `random` package supports only strict `ST`. So what's the workaround?

Comment: Why not `randomOrdering = toEnum <$> randomRIO (0, 2)`? The implementation of `randomRIO` is already bias-free.

Comment: @DanielWagner I actually wanted a general way of representing an arbitrary probability space.

Comment: Have you considered [`randomRs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRs)? E.g. `randomRs (1,3) <$> initStdGen` ? I can't understand if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: What is a "probability space"? Is this another word for distribution? If so, you're out of luck; there are uncomputable distributions. So you'll have to narrow things down *somehow*. Can you say more about what you want to do that leads you to want "arbitrary probability spaces"?

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way of generating a lazy infinite pseudorandom stream using `System.Random` is to use `randoms`.  For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Word

import System.Random
main = do
  infwords :: [Word64] <- randoms <$> newStdGen
  print $ take 10 infwords
```

Here, `infwords` is a normal, lazy, infinite Haskell list of pseudorandom `Word64`s.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems you want to work with a *lazy* list (or stream) of random numbers via `getWordString`, and then consume it in the pure function `randomOrderingMap`. Not an unreasonable approach to play around with, but creating such a lazy list, and actually deferring the execution of the next call to `getWordString`, requires lazy IO.

So if you replace the recursive call to `getWordString` with `unsafeInterleaveIO getWordString` (see [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO)), then it should work.

Try adding a `putStrLn` statement to `getWordString` to observe when exactly the IO action in this function is executed.

This is not necessarily the most direct or idiomatic way of solving this problem, and usually one does not reach for unsafe function, but as a learning experience this is useful.